# Twitter bootstrap3 Carousel autoslide doesn't work before click to carousel controls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

i have twitter-bootstrap 3 carousel application. but autoslide property works only if i click carousel controls once. I jut want to autoslide immediately when the page is loaded. here is my code, thanks for help.
Hello, i have twitter-bootstrap 3 carousel application. but autoslide property works only if i click carousel controls once. I jut want to autoslide immediately when the page is loaded. here is my code, thanks for help.

```
<div class="container carouselbg">
    <div id="a-carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#a-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#a-carousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
            <li data-target="#a-carousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="1" >
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Açıklama</h1>
                    <p> Açıklama yazısı gel</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="1" >
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Açıklama</h1>
                    <p> Açıklama yazısı gel</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="1" >
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Açıklama</h1>
                    <p> Açıklama yazısı gel</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#a-carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#a-carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


$('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 1200
        });
```

Comment: Problem is solved, there was a script error which is not about carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem was that there was javascripts errors on the page.
Have you checked it firebug or developer tools?

[image]

Comment: which tool is it? by the way thanks i solved via firebug :) there was a script error.

Comment: This is Google Chrome and the chrome developer tools. But you can also use Chromium

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your JScript

$('#a-carousel').carousel({
            interval: 1200
        });